# Qt designer preview different from actual GUI in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, preview

When I try to run this code from converted ui to .py, my first page for my stacked widget seems to have lost it's stylesheet that I have given it in the desginer, but the other pages in the stacked widgets are fine when I tested them too. Pls help

Preview: Fusion Style:[image: Preview : Fusion Style]

Preview: Windows Vista Style:[image: Preview: WindowsVista Style]

Preview: Window Xp Style:[image: Preview: WindowsXp Style]

Preview: Windows Style:[image: Preview: Windows Style]

Actual Gui:[image: The actual gui when compiled in Python]

Here's the ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1080</width>
    <height>720</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">*{
background-color:qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0.5, y1:0.539409, x2:0.5, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(116, 119, 131, 255), stop:1 rgba(145, 148, 163, 255));
}
</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="loginForm">
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>1</width>
       <height>1</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>540</width>
       <height>610</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="accessibleName">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true"/>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="currentIndex">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="titleWindow">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>540</width>
        <height>610</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="accessibleName">
       <string>titleWindowContainer</string>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QWidget{
border-radius: 15px;
background:none;
}

QWidget[accessibleName = titleWindowContainer]{
border: 5px solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
background: rgb(107, 113, 140);
}

</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="titleLabel">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>-1</x>
         <y>-1</y>
         <width>541</width>
         <height>401</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>1</width>
         <height>1</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel{
background: none;
font: 60px &quot;Imprint MT Shadow&quot;;
qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;

}</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</string>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="adminLoginButton">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>30</x>
         <y>430</y>
         <width>171</width>
         <height>101</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>1</width>
         <height>1</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QPushButton:hover{
background: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0.5, y1:0.539409, x2:0.5, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(116, 119, 131, 255), stop:1 rgba(145, 148, 163, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton{
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.503, y1:1, x2:0.503, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(82, 87, 120, 255), stop:1 rgba(125, 130, 127, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton:pressed{
background: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:0.9995, x2:0.477, y2:0.522955, stop:0.154229 rgba(104, 111, 153, 255), stop:1 rgba(152, 163, 223, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid black;
}

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ADMIN</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="memberLoginButton">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>340</x>
         <y>430</y>
         <width>171</width>
         <height>101</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>1</width>
         <height>1</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QPushButton:hover{
background: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0.5, y1:0.539409, x2:0.5, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(116, 119, 131, 255), stop:1 rgba(145, 148, 163, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton{
background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.503, y1:1, x2:0.503, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(82, 87, 120, 255), stop:1 rgba(125, 130, 127, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

QPushButton:pressed{
background: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:0.9995, x2:0.477, y2:0.522955, stop:0.154229 rgba(104, 111, 153, 255), stop:1 rgba(152, 163, 223, 255));
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid black;
}

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>MEMBER</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="loginAsLabel">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>200</x>
         <y>430</y>
         <width>141</width>
         <height>101</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>1</width>
         <height>1</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel{
background: none;
font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;;
}</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>LOGIN AS</string>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="memberLoginWidget">
      <property name="accessibleName">
       <string>memberLoginContainer</string>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QWidget{
border-radius: 15px;
background:none;
}

QWidget[accessibleName = memberLoginContainer]{
border: 5px solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
background: rgb(107, 113, 140);
}
</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="loginInputFrame_member">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>240</y>
         <width>540</width>
         <height>370</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="memberUsername">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
          <pointsize>13</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(152, 161, 199);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:hover{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(181, 192, 236);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:focus{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 160, 6);
padding-left: 10px;
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>username</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="memberPassword">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>230</y>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
          <pointsize>13</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(152, 161, 199);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:hover{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(181, 192, 236);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:focus{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 160, 6);
padding-left: 10px;
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>password</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="memberHomeButton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>310</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>61</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="icon">
         <iconset>
          <normaloff>images/login.png</normaloff>images/login.png</iconset>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>41</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="pixmap">
         <pixmap>images/user3.png</pixmap>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>230</y>
          <width>41</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="pixmap">
         <pixmap>images/browser.png</pixmap>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="memberLoginImage">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>150</x>
         <y>130</y>
         <width>241</width>
         <height>261</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="pixmap">
        <pixmap>images/id-card.png</pixmap>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="memberTitle">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>541</width>
         <height>191</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Imprint MT Shadow</family>
         <pointsize>-1</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel{
background: none;
font: 50px &quot;Imprint MT Shadow&quot;;
qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
}</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>MEMBER LOGIN</string>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="margin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="adminLoginWidget">
      <property name="accessibleName">
       <string>adminLoginContainer</string>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QWidget{
border-radius: 15px;
background: rgb(107, 113, 140);
}

QWidget[accessibleName = adminLoginContainer]{
border: 5px solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
background: rgb(107, 113, 140);
}
</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="loginInputFrame_admin">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>240</y>
         <width>540</width>
         <height>370</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background:none;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="adminUsername">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
          <pointsize>13</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(152, 161, 199);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:hover{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(181, 192, 236);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:focus{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 160, 6);
padding-left: 10px;
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>username</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="adminPasswordInput">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>150</x>
          <y>230</y>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>240</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Arial</family>
          <pointsize>13</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(152, 161, 199);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:hover{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(181, 192, 236);
padding-left: 10px;
}

QLineEdit:focus{
background:rgb(114, 120, 149);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 160, 6);
padding-left: 10px;
}</string>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>password</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="adminHomeButton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>310</y>
          <width>61</width>
          <height>61</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="icon">
         <iconset>
          <normaloff>images/login.png</normaloff>images/login.png</iconset>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>41</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="pixmap">
         <pixmap>images/user3.png</pixmap>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>230</y>
          <width>41</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
        <property name="pixmap">
         <pixmap>images/browser.png</pixmap>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="adminLoginImage">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>150</x>
         <y>130</y>
         <width>241</width>
         <height>261</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background:none;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="pixmap">
        <pixmap>images/id-card.png</pixmap>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="adminTitle">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>541</width>
         <height>191</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Imprint MT Shadow</family>
         <pointsize>-1</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">QLabel{
background: none;
font: 50px &quot;Imprint MT Shadow&quot;;
qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
}</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string> ADMINISTRATOR LOGIN</string>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="margin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Hello John! could you also try the other previews? I think there are other previews styles there on the qt designer, 3 I think... could you check it out and if possible add it to the question too :D Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I got 4 preview styles, please check them out. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to see other preview styles if it is the same as your actual GUI when being run? Ohh.. it seems okay...

Comment: YES! they are the same on the preview when being run but ONLY on the other pages which I mentioned that seem to be working fine, but when it comes to this first page, they dnt work.

Comment: @JohnEmanuelAlamares share the .ui file and try: `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: I shared the ui now, I already tried setting the app style to each preview styles I have and they all work except on the first page of the stacked widget.

Comment: What if you remove the generic `QWidget* {...}` and add the border radius property to the selector? I know it would break the borders of the other child widgets, but it's just for testing purposed. Also, you should not use the `accessibleName` property as a selector, since that property is intended for screen readers only (and is potentially localized), and the object name (`Class#objectName {}`) selector should be used instead.